# Реализация поиска

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Возник вопрос, как реализуют поиск в приложениях. Допустим у нас есть 5 параметров по которым можно осуществлять поиск сотрудников: Период времени устройства на работу (начало периода, конец периода); Имя; Фамилия; Отчество. Искать можно по любому из параметров (как только по имени [все остальное игнорируется], так и полностью ФИО, так и по всем параметрам вместе взятым).
В сервис приходит объект типа:

```
public class SearchContext
{
    public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

Как будет корректно осуществить поиск в таблице по данным параметрам ? Как вариант можно нагородить ифов типа:

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(SearchContext searchContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContext.Name) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContext.SecondName) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContext.MiddleName) &&
            searchContext.BeginDate.HasValue && searchContext.EndDate.HasValue)
            return _employeeDAO.GetEmployeesByPeriod(searchContext.BeginDate.Value, searchContext.EndDate);
        //.....продолжаем проверять разные условия
    }
```

Вторым вариантом будет создать какой-нибудь специальный класс типа ExpressionBuilder, тогда код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(SearchContext searchContext)
    {
        var builder = new ExpressionBuilder<Employee>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContext.Name))
            builder = builder.Property(x => x.Name).AreEquals(searchContext.Name);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContext.SecondName))
            builder = builder.Property(x => x.SecondName).AreEquals(searchContext.SecondName);

        var condition = builder.Build();
        return _employeeDAO.GetEmployeesByQuery(condition);
    }
```

Второй вариант кажется более удачным так как читаемость метода улучшается. Хочется услышать мнение знающих людей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант влоб - использовать LINQ и IQueryable (раз уж тег стоит). Или свою реализацию Query Object:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(SearchContext searchContext)
{
    var result = _employeesContext.Employees; // IQueryable<Employee>

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContext.Name))
    {
        result = result.Where(e => e.Name == searchContext.Name);
    }
    // ...

    return result;
}
```

но if-ы никуда не денутся.

Более красивый вариант - завести отдельные классы для различных условий

```
public class NameCondition : ICondition
{
    IQueryable<Employee> ApplyTo(IQueryable<Employee> source)
    {
        return.Where(e => e.Name == searchContext.Name);
    }
}
```

и вместо SearchContext таскать список условий:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(SearchContext searchContext)
{
    var result = _employeesContext.Employees; // IQueryable<Employee>

    foreach (var condition in searchContext.Conditions)
    {
        result = condition.ApplyTo(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

вобщем, все упирается в ваш `_employeeDAO` - если он умеет LINQ - то стоит использовать LINQ. Если не умеет - то придется придумывать свой велосипед (например, написать свой LINQ-провайдер, это достаточно просто).

Comment: как тогда правильно реализовывать DAO (с EntityFramework) ? А то я обычно делаю просто набор функция типа GetEmployeeById(Guid id), GetEmployeesByName(string name), и так далее, в самом DAO просто пишу что-то типа: context.Employees.Where(x => x.Name == name).ToList();

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev это обширная тема, и мнений по ней очень много. от "EF - это готовая реализация DAO, не нужно поверх ее самописных оберток" до "делаем изолирующую обертку, с типа своей реализацией репозитория и unit of work на сонове готовых их реализаций в EF". я бы посоветовал не усложнять, и взять первый вариант :)